# Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, big-list, vote-to-undelete, undelete-request

`There is a similar popular question at` [MSE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-10-2012-12-2014).

The purpose of this thread is to help focus the attention of the community on posts that may require exceptional handling. This includes **requests for reopen and undeletion votes**. A request should be posted as an answer below.

Please do not use this thread to engage in debates on contentious matters (e.g. reasons for closure). That should be done in a separate linked thread. The goal is to keep this meta thread free of tension, so that everyone feels comfortable posting here. Please be polite, and respect the many different viewpoints in our diverse community.

Comment: Why not just pop into chat and ask one of the mod team?

Comment: Or of course more generally 'people who are about'

Comment: BTW, any specific question(s) as a prompt for asking?

Comment: we typically handle this in chat room.

Comment: I'm not sure that such a question is needed here. There are plenty of experienced users in the chat almost all the time, and for the number of questions of this sort we get on meta, it's not likely to be a problem to just continue with individual posts as they arise.

Comment: isnt this better than chat-room? this has benefits of   chat-room and some advantages. e.g. in this way not only Present users (of chat) can help, also others can help; just now in some parts of the planet is midnight.

Comment: @user1 We have relatively few questions that I'm aware of that need 'help to reopen', so to-date one-off meta questions/chat requests seem to have worked. Certainly things can be missed in chat and for more complex cases a meta thread is useful, but I'm not seeing why each can't be handled on its own merits.